# How do I change this Unix command to run in PuTTY or Plink on Windows

Tags: ssh, unix, putty, ssh-tunnel, plink

```
ssh -L 5432:anRDSDATABASE.rAndomLe34.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p admin@12.345.67.891" ubuntu@12.34.5.678
```

I am struggling to work out how transform the above simple unix ssh command which creates an SSH tunnel and forwards my local port over a jump node and proxy to a postgres database hosted my AWS RDS.

Comment: show us you attempt at it please... which configurations did you tried?

Comment: Hi, I'm not really sure where to start, partly because i don't understand the unix command itself very well, but as I understand it, the first part **5432:anRDSDATABASE.rAndomLe34.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432** means open the tunnel and expose the port 5432

and **-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p admin@12.345.67.891" ubuntu@12.34.5.678** means proxy through bastion host with an additional jump to get my into the right VPC in AWS

You might have guessed by my descriptions, i am not very au fait with this

Comment: it would likely be helpful to include your comment in the body of the question

Answer (score 0):

```
plink -A -proxycmd "plink -A -nc 12.34.5.678:22 admin@12.345.67.891"  -L  3333:ANAQSRDSPOSTGRES.amazonaws.com:5432 ubuntu@12.34.5.678:22
```

Answer above